# Redraw google maps on parent container resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got a google map api v3 on a page and when enlarged to full window size it doesn't redraw itself. You can see the problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cmmx8uyk/)

I've looked at what people say in similar questions and I found that everyone seems to be solving this problem with this line of code.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

I've tried it, but it didn't seem to help. Your feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: trigger the resize-event of `window` instead

Comment: I am not resizing a browser window. Only an html element gets resized.

Comment: But the listener that sets the center of the map is bound to the resize-event of window, not of the map. Furthermore the API internally observes the resize-event of the window and redraws the map.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems to work for me... (see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n5c01zw5/))

Basically, just adding `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` doesn't help, you call it on the `map` object you instantiated...

Comment: You are very right. I was just writing my own answer, however yours seem to be more elegant. I was instantiating a new google maps function on every click, which isn't very efficient. It served a purpose though. It's definitely a better practice to store maps function in a global variable and access it whenever I need it. Thanks a lot.