# How to redraw google embedded map?

Tags: google-maps, iframe

I'm using Google's embed map API as a custom editor in our CMS to allow our clients to easily create responsive Google Maps or Directions Maps on their site -- I've got the map rendering and responsive as the window resizes but I don't see any way to force a 'redraw' of the map.  I've hunted through their dev docs https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/ and can't seem to find anything about redrawing the map.  When I look through google, I only find examples of redrawing through the Javascript API but as this is just an IFRAME on the page, there's no javascript variable assigned to the map that I can just trigger the 'resize' event on.  Does Google support what I'm attempting to do?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the problem?

Comment: @geocodezip As the window resizes - the iframe / google map also resizes with the content / page, but the location on the map is no longer centered and at some viewports gets completely lost on the map

Answer (score 0):

You can redraw/refresh iframe by calling `resize` you should use the Google map events, options and method to change the contents of maps.

[`google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#event)

You can resize the iframe to suit the structure and design of your own website, note that embedded maps are not supported below a size of 200px in either dimension.

Here's a related SO ticket tuckled how to redraw maps: [Redraw google maps on parent container resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294996/redraw-google-maps-on-parent-container-resize) / http://forums.asp.net/t/1987472.aspx?Is+it+possible+to+refresh+update+the+infoboxes+in+Google+Maps

Comment: This does not answer the original question, which was about the [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start), not the Javascript API